# ASPXGRIDVIEW date value is different from what i have selected in a gridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a grid-view in that one column is receipt-date which is nothing but selecting the date from the calendar. In my code behind I check the value by something like this.

```
if value.GetValue(0) = "Receipt Date" Then
Dim rdate As Date = value.GetValue(1)
```

I have selected 25-4-2015
but what I am getting in `value.GetValue(1)` is *25-4-0115*.
How is the year getting changed is my question here.